# How to close `react-burger-menu` by clicking outside the menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to close `react-burger-menu` by clicking outside the menu?

I use: https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu

```
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

class Example extends React.Component {
  showSettings (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    .
    .
    .
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Menu>
        <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
        <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <a onClick={ this.showSettings } className="menu-item--small" href="">Settings</a>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu#overlay says "You can disable the overlay click event (i.e. prevent overlay clicks from closing the menu) with disableOverlayClick." so the behaviour you are asking for is the *default* behaviour.

Comment: Maybe it is broken because you didn't finish following the setup instructions: https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu#properties

Comment: @Quentin but I can't see overlay. I click next to menu, but it doesn;t work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.  So if you had the same problem I had where using an onClick to change the menus state worked but reloaded the page and you lose that nice transition effect, do this.

Instead of changing the menus state, just click the overlay as if you were closing the menu by clicking back on the page you were on:

```
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName("bm-overlay")[0] as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
```

This solution might not be future proof in the case that you update the react burger menu and suddenly the 'bm-overlay' doesn't exist anymore but that seems pretty unlikely and this should work every time.  This way you can let the menu handle the state of the 'isOpen' all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing the complete solution. But seem like  menu component from react-burger-menu has prop called isOpen. You can actually modify and use it according to your usecase.
https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu/wiki/FAQ#i-want-to-control-the-open-state-programmatically-but-i-dont-understand-how-to-use-the-isopen-prop

Comment: Just how to call the function by clicking outside the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You will get **.bm-overly** class from **react-burger-menu**.

> Note: Clicking on this overlay will automatically close the burger menu
> but you will need to spread the overlay to the entire screen as below

**If you are using menu aligning left side:**

```
.bm-overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

**If you are using menu aligning right side:**

```
.bm-overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```